# Automatic web shop creation

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

In one of my projects, I need to have automatic webshop creation.

It will be similar to [bigcartel.com](http://bigcartel.com/).

Is there any tutorial available?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at http://www.getshop.com, it is easy and fairly cheap. If not, you got Shopify, http://www.shopify.com, but in my opinion, Getshop is a much better choice, due to prices and overall usability.

Answer (score 1):

You can try oscommerce and modify it to support multiple shops
osCommerce Online Merchant is an Open Source online shop e-commerce solution

http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/70365-multi-stores-multiple-shops-support/page__st__1440

You will need to modify it more so that it supports the creation of the stores.